# gtk-launch autocomplete is very slow

Tags: troubleshooting, zsh, autocomplete, gtk

Am using zsh with zsh-completions on arch linux. Whenever i press tab after `gtk-launch` it takes very long (3-4 seconds) to load suggestions, even if i type a partial word. What could be the cause for such a long time to load suggestions, and could there be a way to speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Gnome, so I cannot reproduce your issue, but the [completion function for `gtk-launch`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/blob/master/src/_gtk-launch) is tiny, so it's not that hard to profile it yourself.

On the command line, do the following:

```bsh
% zmodload zsh/zprof
% gtk-launch <TAB> # Wait for the completion to finish, then press ^C.
% zprof
```

`zprof` will show you exactly how much time has been spent in which function.

Comment: I don't use Gnome either. Am just using it to execute `.desktop` files. Is there an alternative to execute them?

Comment: I have no idea. I don't use `.desktop` files.